# Query JSONB through dblink (Oracle <> Postgres)

Tags: oracle, postgresql, jsonb, dblink

We have a local db (Oracle) where we want to query a remote db (postgres), the data to be retreived is in JSONB format.

What is the best way for achieving this ?

Answer (score 1):

The tool for accessing PostgreSQL from Oracle database is GoldenGate.

The [12.2 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/c1221/gg-winux/GIPSQ/sysreq.htm#GIPSQ121) does not even list the `jsonb` data type, so it is probably is not supported (I guess Oracle didn't check PostgreSQL's documentation since 9.2, when `json` was introduced).

But then Oracle doesn't have a special JSON data type anyway, it stores JSON as `VARCHAR2` or `CLOB`, so you can easily use a view in PostgreSQL that casts the `jsonb` to `text` and use that.